# Dynamically Scaling SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm working on a site where users can manipulate an SVG image through a couple of textboxes.
I would like to have the SVG scale to fit the container div.

For example, if the SVG was exactly the container's height and 10 pixels wide, then doubling the height would cause the apparent width to be 5 pixels.

My page is split roughly in half, with the numbers on the left and the image on the right. Resizing the browser thus causes the SVG's container element to change shape, meaning that I can't hardcode the container's dimensions in the SVG.

Every solution I've found online uses the `viewBox` attribute; however, I can't find a way to apply that without having a hard-coded container size.

Here is a fiddle with my editor setup:

https://jsfiddle.net/xyjs5b63/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjusting `viewBox` sounds like what you want. I'm not sure what you were doing that made it not work.

```js
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

var height_elem = inputs[0];
var width_elem = inputs[1];

height_elem.value = '100';
width_elem.value = '100';

height_elem.addEventListener("change", valueChange);
width_elem.addEventListener("change", valueChange);

function valueChange() {
    svg.setAttribute('viewBox', "0 0 "+width_elem.value+" "+height_elem.value);
}

valueChange();
```

```css
#out {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: honeydew;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="in">
        <input type="number"><br>
        <input type="number">
    </div>
    <div id="out">
        <svg>
            <rect width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var rect = document.querySelector('rect');
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

var height_elem = inputs[0];
var width_elem = inputs[1];

height_elem.value = '100';
width_elem.value = '100';

height_elem.addEventListener("change", valueChange);
width_elem.addEventListener("change", valueChange);

function valueChange() {
max = parseInt(height_elem.value) >= parseInt(width_elem.value) ? 'h' : 'w';
if (max == 'h') {
 rect.setAttribute('height', "100%");
 rect.setAttribute('width', (width_elem.value * 100 / height_elem.value)+"%");
}
else {
 rect.setAttribute('width', "100%");
 rect.setAttribute('height', (height_elem.value * 100 / width_elem.value)+"%");
}
}

valueChange();
```

```css
#main {
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
}

#in {
float: left;
width: 40%;
height: 100%
}

#out {
margin: 10%;
width: 20vw;
height: 20vw;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
<div id="in">
    Height: <input type="number"><br>
    Width: <input type="number">
</div>
<br>
<div id="out">
    <svg height="auto">
    <rect></rect></svg>
</div>
</div>
```

Does this solve your problem?